# How to create users in Django's backend database when using Vue.js and Auth0 for frontend authentication

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, auth0

I am trying to use Vue.js as a frontend, and Django as the backend for an SPA.

In the frontend, I am leveraging Auth0 for user authentication and I want to send the id_token obtained from user registration/creation from Auth0 to the backend to create specific user profiles in real-time.

How do I create user profiles on my django backend for every user when they register using Auth0 on vue.js on the frontend?

Previously, I was using the following code to enable profile creation once a user is created:

```
# Whenever a User account is created, it creates a profile for it too.

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        user_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
        user_profile.save()
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

In simpler terms, this is what I am trying to achieve:
- User registers on the website
- Account is created by leveraging Auth0
- user_id from Auth0 is fetched and sent to the backend (Django) from the frontend (Vue.js)
- Django creates a user profile for the registered user in its backend postgresql database.
- User is now able to access his profile page http://website/profile once logged in. (Data for the profile is fetched from Django)

I am fairly new to Vue.js and Javascript. Although Vue.js is a breeze to use, but I can't seem to figure out how to replicate similar functionality in Vue.js with Auth0.

Any help/guidance/pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do I create user profiles on my django backend for every user when they register using Auth0 on vue.js on the frontend?

Comment: @U.Tayyab is your problem communicating from front to back, or the actual user profile creation process ?

Comment: A bit of both. I need my front-end to connect to the backend and pass in user_id obtained from Auth0 for every user upon registration. Then use this user_id to create User Profiles on the django backend.
Therefore, allowing every user to have their own profile automatically generated via backend once they register.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make Ajax calls - I recommend [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) - to communicate between your client and server sides. It's pretty straightforward, I've been using it with Vue.js & love it.

Something like:

in `auth.vue`:

```
axios.post('/yourUserRoute', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

If you make sure that you call this axios call every time you want to register a new user, your back-end will receive the correct informations for you to proceed on your server. I never touched Django so I'm not going to try and help you on the details, but this should give you a good start to work with!